# Display a number of textboxes based on count and insert into database Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display a set of textboxes based on the amount that was selected from from a drop down list. Say I select 5 then it should display 5 textboxes; the textbox is displayed however on page load it clears the boxes. Additionally I would like to enter those data entered into database table.

```
protected void ddlCount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(ddlCount.SelectedItem.Value); i++)
    {

        TextBox tx = new TextBox();
        tx.ID = "tx" + i;
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tx);
        ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    }
}
```

Button Click

```
  protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   foreach (Control ctrl in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls)
                    {
                        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                        {
                        Label ll = (Label)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("Label5");
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            comm.CommandText = "PP_CreateUserNumber";
                            comm.Connection = con;    
                            comm.Parameters.Add("@sealNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 11; 
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
 }
```

Comment: Is this a traditional Web Forms application? If so the controls actually need to be created in the Page Initialize command every single time the page is created otherwise the viewstate will not track the text box changes.

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: See my edited comment. The controls need to be created on every page load in Page_Intialize

Comment: @Matt; what about the insert into database. and how would I keep track because I had added this ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl()); and the data still clears out

Comment: FYI, you might want to get the count as an integer once before the loop rather than convert it on each iteration.

Comment: ok thanks for that

Comment: @Jane the data is clearing out because of where the text boxes are being created. If you create the text boxes earlier then you will get the controls on save and the content should be there.

Comment: ok, I understand; but I don't understand how to insert into the database

Comment: You may want to use a `GridView` or `Repeater` control.

Comment: @Matt; can you show me example to stop the data from clearing on button click, thought I had fixed it but it is still clearing out